# Efficient way to download gigabyte files from SFTP server programmatically

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp

I have several 30GB files on the SFTP server. I want to download them programmatically. Currently I am using [sftp](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/sftp.htm) get command to download them, but the time to download each file is about 3.5 hours. Is there a way to download these files fast?

Comment: There are commercial file-transfer products that can be much faster than TCP-based protocols like SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, the limiting factor here is the speed of your network.  `sftp` and SSH in general will use as much bandwidth as possible unless you've restricted them in some way.

The speed you're getting is about 2.38 MB/s, which is a reasonable download speed over a home network connection, but would be unreasonably slow on a LAN.  You haven't said which you're using, though.

It is theoretically possible that the encryption is too slow if (a) you're using an AES algorithm and one side doesn't support AES in hardware or (b) you're on a 10 Gb network.  However, I very much doubt that's the case here, since all algorithms in modern OpenSSH versions can max out a 1 Gib connection.

I would investigate the speed and configuration of the network if you're on a LAN, or the speed of the SFTP server or disk if one side is an appliance or embedded device.

Comment: Thank you. The download is fast when I use cyberduck to connect to sftp server and download the file from the server using it.  Just that while programmatic download with sftp get command, the download is too slow. Why is the difference in speed when using cyberduck and sftp get to download same file ?

Comment: Latency is another important factor that can cause SFTP not to *"use as much bandwidth as possible"* - See [Speed up SFTP uploads on high latency network?](https://serverfault.com/q/843691/168875)

Comment: If you think it's the `sftp` tool, you can try using `curl` if your version is built with SFTP support.  Debian's is, and Ubuntu disco's is, but not earlier versions of Ubuntu.